# PROC SQL Conditional Insert Into Using GT and LT

Tags: sql, insert, sas, proc

I need to insert a bunch of rows, blank rows, except for my sasdate var, which I need to be a result of this condition:
    `if (17530 < sasdate < 20800) then sasdate = .`

But I can't seem to do it.

```
proc sql;
create table ds as
select  sasdate, avg(x) as avg_x
from ds1
group by sasdate;
insert into ds
if (17530 <= sasdate <= 20800) then .;
quit;
```

Where am I going wrong??
I know for starters that I probably can't use the `if` statement in here, but I don't know what else to use.

Basically I want to add a bunch of rows to the top of my dataset where the first sasdate = 17530, and then the nonblank (the dataset I'm adding to, ds) starts with sasdate = 20800.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: May be what you want is, for example : insert into ds values(17530, .); for the first row. this row is added at the end of the dataset.

Comment: Do you want to group by the original SASDATE or the new re-coded value?

Answer (score 2):

I think you want a `case` expression.  For instance, this will null-out the `sasdate` values in your range:

```
create table ds as
    select (case when sasdate < 17530 or sasdate > 20800 then sasdate end) as sasdate,
           avg(x) as avg_x
    from ds1
    group by ds1.sasdate;
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL does not have a built-in iterator or looping syntax for creating new rows.  You can right join to a separate table of dates covering every day in a range to 'fill-in' the days of the 'left' table.

The function for averaging is `MEAN`

For example:

```
data alldays;
  do date = 17530 to 20800;
    output;
  end;
run;

data have;
  date = 20800;
  x = 1;
  do sequence = 1 to 10;
    x = sum (x, lag(x));
    output;
  end;
run;

proc sql; 
  create table have_ave as 
  select date, mean (x) as mean_x
  from have
  group by date;

  create table want as
  select 
    coalesce (have_ave.date, alldays.date) as date
  , mean_x
  from have_ave 
  right join alldays on have_ave.date = alldays.date
  ;
```